# Remove or add any elemt from magento2 Collection?

Tags: remove, add

I have order `collection` and i want to add one more column in this collection . 
How can possible ?

whats the `addBindParam()` or  `addItem()` method do ?

`/vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php`

this method return `revenue` of order that show in dashboard `Last Orders`

```
 public function addRevenueToSelect($convertCurrency = false)
    {

        $expr = $this->getTotalsExpression(
            !$convertCurrency,
            $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_refunded', 0),
            $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_canceled', 0),
            $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_discount_canceled', 0)
        );
        $this->getSelect()->columns(['revenue' =>$expr]);
        $this->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('finset'=>1));
        //die( 'last order');
        return $this;
    }
```

here i filter orders by `addFieldToFilter` but i also want to change revenue element in this collection.

i want to get entity_id from this collection and then call model of `sales_order_item` and get price the add and return `revenue` for each order.

Comment: Please update you code @HaFizUmer

Comment: okay please check it am updating . . .

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran please review code . i updated